# A Python Exception error in gdb 7.10

Tags: gdb

I have installed `gdb 7.10` under `Ubuntu 14.04` by compiling from the source as detailed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/529795/111162) answer (with the only exception that I copied the executable into `/usr/bin`). When I execute commands in `gdb`, I get the following error:

```
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing:
```

What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Related [getting python exeception in gdb when "(gdb) step"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948246/getting-python-exeception-in-gdb-when-gdb-step/70102483)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What can I do to get rid of it?

GDB wants to install *more* than just the GDB binary. To make a complete installation, remove `/usr/bin/gdb` and do `make install`.

Comment: This worked. But why did they suggest to not perform `make install` in the comments to the linked answer?

Comment: what if GDB was installed binary?