# getting python exeception in gdb when "(gdb) step"

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am getting python exception when I step the line of code. What I want is to step into or step over but I am getting this exception when I type `(gdb) step` and bang throws exception. I compiled the code with `-g` flag. throwing this exception

> Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:

> Thread 3 "s1.o" hit Breakpoint 2, get_payload_to_send (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:
> p=0x55555555a2c0, pay=0x7ffff75bfe78) at ServerHi1.c:679
> warning: Source file is more recent than executable.

> 679                 char c[20];
> (gdb) step

> Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:

> Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is
> missing:

> Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:

> Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:

> __inet_addr (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:
> cp=0x55555555a6d2 "192.168.10.25") at inet_addr.c:210
> 210     inet_addr.c: No such file or directory.

> (gdb)

What I want is step into/ step over single line. Coding in C

gdb version: GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git

Comment: This sounds like you gdb installation is broken. `gdb._execute_unwinders` should be in `share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py`.

Comment: How to fix the installation?

Answer (score 1):

I installed `gdb 11.1` from source and I was having the same error. I fixed by manually copying the python files into `/usr/share/gdb/python`, i.e.:

1. `cd gdb-11.1`
2. `make`
3. `make install`
4. `cp -r ./gdb/python/lib/gdb/ /usr/share/gdb/python`

Extra: Full steps for installing gcc 11.1 from source on Debian 10 as `gdb111` instead of `gdb` (i.e., not overriding your system gdb):

```
apt update &&
apt install texinfo subversion wget \
    libgmp-dev python3-dev libncurses5-dev libsource-highlight &&
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-11.1.tar.gz &&
tar xvzf gdb-11.1.tar.gz &&
cd gdb-11.1 &&
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gdb111 \
    --program-suffix=111 --with-python=python3 \
    --enable-tui=yes --with-curses --enable-gold=yes \
    --enable-ld=yes --enable-libada --enable-libssp \
    --enable-lto --enable-vtable-verify --enable-werror \
    --enable-source-highlight &&
make -j `nproc` &&
make install &&
rsync --recursive ./gdb/python/lib/gdb/ /usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/ &&
perl -pi -e '!$x && s/function black b;/function b;/i && ($x=1)' \
    /usr/share/source-highlight/esc.style &&
printf 'set debug-file-directory /usr/lib/debug/\n' >> ~/.gdbinit &&
cp /usr/local/gdb111/bin/gdb111 /bin/
```

Alternatively, instead of copy the files manually into your system, you cold run gdb with the parameter, e.g., `gdb111 -p $(pidof someprocess) --data-directory /path/to/source/gdb-11.1/gdb/data-directory`.

If you are not installing from source like this, you can reinstall/restore your gdb installation with `sudo apt install --reinstall gdb`

#### Update

Inside a Dockerfile recipe, you need to run perl in a separate step:

```
RUN perl -pi -e '!$x && s/function black b;/function b;/i && ($x=1)' /usr/share/source-highlight/esc.style
RUN svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python /root/gdb_stl_python \
    && printf 'python \nimport sys \nsys.path.insert(0, "/root/gdb_stl_python") \nfrom libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers \nregister_libstdcxx_printers (None) \nend \n' >> /root/.gdbinit
```

References:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/102449/how-to-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package
3. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1688372 -  New gdb terminal colors are unreadable on GNOME Terminal "dark" theme